# Preserved curvature of Levi Civita connections implies what in terms of metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, connections

Let $f:M\to N$ be a diffeomorphism, $g^M$ and $g^N$ the metric tensors on $M$ and $N$, and $R^M$ and $R^N$ the curvature tensors of the respective Levi-Civita connections. Let $f$ be such that $R^N = f_* R^M$.

What can we say about $g^M$ and $g^N$, at least locally?

I hope I was clear with the notation.

EDIT: In other words, I am looking for some sort of result that generalizes Spivak's "Test Case" for nonzero curvatures.

Comment: [This MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100281/does-the-curvature-determine-the-metric) has some relevant discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. It seems that locally we have the existence of a metric for a given Ricci curvature. I don't know how to use this though...